# Sticky header that is transparent over main banner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, squarespace

I've built a [client's site](https://keren-lerner-h06c.squarespace.com) on Squarespace.

I want to create a header that:

1) Has a transparent background when the user first arrives on the page
2) When the user scrolls down, gets a background color and remains affixed to the top of the viewport.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear enough from your question what you want to achieve. Can you please edit it to add some details? You want a normal transparent header (that's in a specific place on the page) or a fixed position, no scroll transparent header (that's in a specific place on the viewport)? You want it to scroll if not at the top of the viewport, but once reached there, be sticky?

Answer (score 0):

### Some info

CSSTricks have a great little example on how to do this (this is the common solution for this).

The basics for this solution is that you listen to the scroll event and check when you get to the right spot (you can calculate that spot programmatically if you want). If you do, you add a class to the header that does the following:

- makes the header colored like you wanted it to be
- make the header `position: fixed; top: <num>;` or `position: absolute; top: <num>` (I've seen both solutions out in the field)

  **!IMPORTANT!** the `position:absolute` solution is less safe, since `position: fixed` positions the element relative to the viewport. `position:absolute` will do the same **only** if it doesn't have any predecessor with a `position:relative` [for more info, check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) ]

There's an experimental css feature for position which will add a `position: sticky` option. In theory, this will do the sticky part by itself [You can see it's experimental by the Experimental Badge next to it on MDN].

### The actual solution

https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/

It also includes a [demo](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/AdaKr) with the code on codepen.io. Just notice that you need to scroll the view box (class="wrap") and not the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine a few things.

First of all, in your css set for the header `position: fixed`

You have then to set the transparency. Something like should be enough: `opacity: 0.5`. You can even use RGBA to specify both color and transparency (I like this one more): `background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)`

Last, you have to bind an handler to to scroll event with JavaScript. If you can use jQuery, something like this should suffice (I suppose you have an element with id="header"):

```
 $("#header").scroll(myScrollHandler);

 function myScrollHandler () {
     if (window.pageYOffset > 50)
     {
         $("#header").fadeTo(200, 0.9);
     } 
     else
     {
         $("#header").fadeTo(200, 0.3);
     } 
 }
```

I used sample values, the first one is the duration in ms, the second the target opacity, where 0 is invisible and 1 is full. In the if I compare the offset of the page to the number of pixels after wich the header will start appearing.

So, to recap, in your css you should have something like this:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

in your html something like this

```
<script>
    $("#header").scroll(myScrollHandler);

     function myScrollHandler () {
         if (window.pageYOffset > 50)
         {
             $("#header").fadeTo(200, 0.9);
         } 
         else
         {
             $("#header").fadeTo(200, 0.5);
         } 
     }
</script>

<div id="header">
    Your header content
</div>
```